# Ionic V2 Prompt Alert to Populate List

Tags: ionic2

I created a prompt alert and I want it to save then populate a list in reverse chronological order.

I'm not getting any errors, I just do not see the items in the list after I click "save."

Here's my code:

```
    public add() {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: "Add Date & Time",
      message: "Enter the date and time of your donation.",
      inputs: [
          {
              name: "donation",
              placeholder: "DD/MM/YYYY"
          },
          {
              name: "time",
              placeholder: "HH:MM AM/PM"
          }
      ],
      buttons: [
          {
              text: "Cancel"
          },
          {
              text: "Save",
              handler: data => {
                  this.donationList.push({
                      name: data.donation,
                      time: data.time
                  });
              }
          }
      ]
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

And here's my html code:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let donation of donationHistoryList">
          {{donation.name}}
          <ion-note item-right>
              {{donation.time}}
          </ion-note>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ts you pushed your data into `donationList`, but in your html `ngFor` you used `donationHistoryList`. The two variables have different names. Try matching the variable names.

Unless you have any other code that matches these variables. Please provide more of your code if I was spotting out the wrong problem. :)